# C# 'select count' sql command incorrectly returns zero rows from sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to return the rowcount from a SQL Server table.  Multiple sources on the 'net show the below as being a workable method, but it continues to return '0 rows'.  When I use that query in management studio, it works fine and returns the rowcount correctly.  I've tried it just with the simple table name as well as the fully qualified one that management studio tends to like.

```
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                cn.ConnectionString = sqlConnectionString;
                cn.Open();

                SqlCommand commandRowCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [LBSExplorer].[dbo].[myTable]", cn);
                countStart = System.Convert.ToInt32(commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
                Console.WriteLine("Starting row count: " + countStart.ToString());
            }
```

Any suggestions on what could be causing it?

Comment: Is `noprimarykey2` a table or a view? The reason why I ask is because it could be a view that filters data by current user.

Comment: It's a table, I've renamed it for clarity.  Thanks

Comment: @Glinkot - and you are sure that you connect to the same SQL Server instance both in Management Studio and the code?

Comment: Yep definitely.  All other operations use the same connectionstring and work like a charm.

Comment: command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Comment: That seemed to do the trick!  Many thanks!  I can't accept a comment as an answer though, pls add an answer if you'd like me to mark it off :)

Comment: no troubles, thanks for your response, we'll see if he sticks it down there otherwise I'll mark yours for use of others :)

Comment: @hamlin11 - isn't `CommandType.Text` default value?

Comment: @Glinkot Posted as answer. Was in a hurry earlier and wasn't sure.  @Alex I don't know, I wasn't sure. Figured it might help the author

Comment: @hamlin11 - this is very weird. I checked, when you create a command without setting `CommandType`, it is already has `CommandType.Text` set. So the answer kind of does not make sense to me, and I really want to understand... :)

Comment: @Alex It's the only thing that I do that he wasn't doing - I don't understand it myself. In the MSDN example here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx), they explicitly set it to the Text Type; however, it is unclear if they are simply demonstrating the fact that you can set it to that value.

Comment: @Alex - if you pull apart the getter for `CommandType` on `SqlCommand`, you'll find that there's weird special casing going on, whereby if the value is currently 0, it lies and says that it's `Text`/1 instead (similarly, from a component/design perspective, the default value is listed as 1). But the actual internal value is left as 0.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Sounds like a bug to me :). But still, this is all weird. I tried the code shown in the question and it worked for me without setting `CommandType`. Hmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Set your CommandType to Text**

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

**More Details** from [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) comment, regarding whether or not .NET defaults SqlCommandTypes to type Text.

If you pull apart the getter for CommandType on SqlCommand, you'll find that there's weird special casing going on, whereby if the value is currently 0, it lies and says that it's Text/1 instead (similarly, from a component/design perspective, the default value is listed as 1). But the actual internal value is left as 0.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand commandRowCount
        = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [LBSExplorer].[dbo].[myTable]", cn))
    {
        commandRowCount.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        var countStart = (Int32)commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting row count: " + countStart.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this better query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) TableName, st.row_count
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE index_id < 2 AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)=N'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: Quite possibly, but it would be helpful if you explained why this is better? Better than using COUNT() I assume?