# How do I retrieve the result of an ADO.NET SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, select

I'm using ASP.NET and I want to find the amount of rows in my table.

I know this is the SQL code: `select count(*) from topics`, but how do I get that to display as a number?

All I want to do is run that code and if it = 0 display one thing but if it's more than 0 display something else.

This is what I have so far:

```
string selectTopics = "select count(*) from topics";
// Define the ADO.NET Objects
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand topiccmd = new SqlCommand(selectTopics, con);
if (topiccmd == 0)
    {
        noTopics.Visible = true;
        topics.Visible = false;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you only need to decide whether or not there are records in the table, I recommend something like "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM topics) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END". This will save you from having to scan the whole table / index.

Comment: Then what would I type to run this for my code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that you must open the connection and execute the command before you can access the result of the SQL query. `ExecuteScalar` returns a *single* result value (different methods must be used if your query will return an multiple columns and / or multiple rows).

Notice the use of the `using` construct, which will safely close and dispose of the connection.

```
string selectTopics = "select count(*) from topics";
// Define the ADO.NET Objects
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   SqlCommand topiccmd = new SqlCommand(selectTopics, con);
   con.Open();
   int numrows = (int)topiccmd.ExecuteScalar();
   if (numrows == 0)
    {
        noTopics.Visible = true;
        topics.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider doing the OP a favour and show how to clean up the connection afterwards (ideally with a `using` block)... :)

Comment: was in the process thanks, there is also the  = vs == and the cast, feel free to improve upon it

Comment: I get the following error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection does not contain a definition for open and no extension method open...`. Is there a namespace I'm missing? And I forgot the double ==. :)

Comment: @dpDesignz Check the [docs for SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx) for starters - it's in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, for which you must reference `System.Data`. If you need more help on specific problems with your code, please edit your question to include that code - otherwise we're left to guess. :)  (And if you have questions beyond the scope of this one, please ask them as separate questions.)

Comment: Yea I have all those that's why I found it weird. Sorry forgot to post those. I'm still getting that error on the open tag though.

Comment: @dpDesignz capitalize Open i.e. con.Open()

Comment: @Gratzy Thanks so much! Didn't notice that edit. :). Also missing the ';' at the end of line 6 & 7.

Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 2):

**ExecuteScalar** is what you're looking for. (method of SqlCommand)

Btw, stick with C#, there's no way PHP is easier.  It's just familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the connection
This might work :

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from topics";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Similar Question: [C# 'select count' sql command incorrectly returns zero rows from sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6326208/1208585)