# Window Form C# MS Access Checking if already has value of that data

Tags: c#, ms-access

How can I check if the data already exists in MS Access? For example, if the name is blouse is Bijan, then when i want to post, the messagebox will display at tell us that Bijan is already in the table.

```
//Button Post
private void buttonPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Connect to database
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;
    //Password need to use [] because it is reserved keyword
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BlouseTable (blouseName,blouseBrand,blouseColor,blouseSize,blouseQuantity) "
        + "VALUES ('" + blouse.BlouseName + "','" + blouse.BlouseBrand
        + "','" + blouse.BlouseColor + "','" + blouse.BlouseSize 
        + "','" + blouse.BlouseQuantity  + "')";

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Display the message result
    MessageBox.Show("Done post new Blouse!");
    //Close the connection after done post new blouse
    connection.Close();
}
```

This is the Button post in my window form. So, when I pressed it, it should the table of database in the MS Access.

Comment: Have you tried the count method?

Comment: Could you show me how to make the count method?

Comment: There are a lot of ways. If you have small list of products you may store everything in memory and check. You can select before inserting. You can use constraints.

Comment: @Reniuz I have a small list of products. Can you show me how to make it?

Comment: First run another query (count) to see if a record already exists. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10577206/1145403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
OleDbCommand commandBlouseName = new OleDbCommand();
commandBlouseName.Connection = connection;
commandBlouseName.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM BlouseTable WHERE blouseName='" + blouse.BlouseName + "'";
OleDbDataReader readerBlouseName = commandBlouseName.ExecuteReader();
int count = 0;
while (readerBlouseName.Read())
{
    count++;
}
if (count == 1)
{
    //Has 1 same name registered
}
if (count < 1)
{
    //Create new one
    //There is no Blouse Name registered with same name
}
if (count > 1)
{
    //More than 1 that Blouse Name registered
}
```