# Storing query count in a vb variable

Tags: database, vb.net

I've been experimenting with what I can do with a database, but I'm unfamiliar with aspects like storing a query result in a variable. I've used this snippet to query my database with more than one record, but the result I keep getting is zero. Can someone explain how this works? Here's my snippet...

```
str = "SELECT COUNT(Nickname) FROM Backup"
cmd.CommandText = str
cmd.Connection = myConn
myConn.Open()
cntPlns = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show(cntPlns.ToString)
```

The connection is there, but my result always comes out zero...thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This doesn't seem like VBA code to me. Please note that VB.NET and VBA are two different languages.

Comment: Point worth noting, Ahmed. Though my form was set up in Visual Studio as VBA...so not sure which would apply.

Comment: Not familiar with ADODB, Nick. But it may be what I'm looking for. I'll have to use the Intellisense to guide me on the syntax....also, I'll take your suggestion about using Count(*)...

Comment: Oh you're right, this probably is in all likelihood .Net, not VBA. Please clarify. Posting all code helps

Comment: If it's VB.Net as tagged, then forget about ADODB

Comment: In this case here's the duplicate, but I can't vote to close again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577174/how-do-i-retrieve-the-result-of-an-ado-net-sqlcommand

Comment: Well, I looked up ADODB.Recordset in Visual Basic, and it didn't have a reference in Intellisense. So I'm not sure where to go with it from there. I know my database select is correct.

Comment: I checked my setup for VS, and the Project I set up was definitely .Net framework. So I guess that's the answer to the code....it's VB.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `ExecuteScalar`, not `ExecuteNonQuery`.  `ExecuteNonQuery` is for executing a non-query, i.e. a SQL statement that does not produce a result set.  `ExecuteScalar` is for executing a query and retrieving a scalar, i.e. a single value, which comes from the first column of the first row of the result set, whether or not that result set contains more data.

For the record, you get zero every time because `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected by the SQL statement, where affected means changed.  A `SELECT` statement affects no rows so zero is the correct result.

It might serve you well to check out my [ADO.NET examples](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) to see what objects and members to use where and when.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what ExecuteScalar. I can see how I was getting the 0 value before. I did run the cmd query as:  cntPlns = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()).  and got the correct result. I'd like to know what the conversion ToInt32 means....

Comment: The return type of `ExecuteScalar` is `Object` because it can return any type of object that can be stored in a database.  If you have `Option Strict On`, which you pretty much always should, you can't assign an `Object` reference to an `Integer` variable so you need to cast/convert from `Object` to `Integer`.  Given that the actual object already is an `Integer`, but boxed inside an `Object` reference, it would actually be more appropriate to use `CInt` for a cast than `Convert.ToInt32` because you're not actually converting anything.

Comment: Oddest thing showing up in my Google browser above the regular VB Forums banner when following the ADO link. A list of PHP errors. Thought you would like to know, if it isn't just me.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the conversion jmc. Good info to know.

Comment: lol...it wasn't just you Mary. But I didn't pay it much mind. Getting good info on all this. Problem solved at this point.

Comment: @Mary, VBForums has been having some issues since a recent vBulletin upgrade. It's a known issue but they're having trouble sorting it.

Answer (score 1):

See [ExecuteNonQuery doesn't return results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349114/executenonquery-doesnt-return-results) for ...nonquery is the wrong cmd.

Try this>>

```
str = "SELECT COUNT(Nickname) as myCount FROM Backup"
cmd.CommandText = str
cmd.Connection = myConn
myConn.Open()
Using cntPlns As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
        If cntPlns.Read Then
             MessageBox.Show(cntPlns.GetInt32(0).ToString)  ' the first column
        End If
End Using
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  There are a number of ways in VB.Net to read a query result ... but `ExecuteNonQuery` is *NOT* one of them ;)

Comment: For a single value, it's more appropriate to call `ExecuteScalar`.  If you were to use a data reader though, at least pass `CommandBehavior.SingleResult` to optimise it.  Also, there's no point testing the result of `Read` in this case because it can't possibly be `False`.  Also, you have provided C# code for a question specifically tagged VB.NET.

Comment: That's true, C# doesn't help me. Though I will probably branch into learning that after I'm more proficient at VB.Net

Comment: revised to vb.net

Comment: @KGCole - please consider upvoting,  and "accepting" the response you find most helpful.